# Empty result from Virtual Member Manager IBM Websphere WAS 8.5

Tags: websphere, virtual-member-manager

I am  using IBM websphere application server, I am trying to access the default file repository from my application using the virtual member manager, below is the code I use, it works well but I got an empty result, I checked the fileRegistry.xml file and it contains users, can anyone tell my where is my problem?

```
DataObject root = SDOHelper.createRootDataObject();
DataObject searchCtrl =   SDOHelper.createControlDataObject(root,null,SchemaConstants.DO_SEARCH_CONTROL);
searchCtrl.getList(SchemaConstants.PROP_PROPERTIES).add("uid"); 
searchCtrl.getList(SchemaConstants.PROP_SEARCH_BASES).add("o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm");
searchCtrl.setString(SchemaConstants.PROP_SEARCH_EXPRESSION,"@xsi:type='PersonAccount' and  uid='*'");
root = getVMMService().search(root);
System.out.println("Output data graph"+  printDO(root));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the getVMMService() method get an instance of LocalServiceProvider ? I run the example in an standAlone app, in the example http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc/dw-w-userrepository/ is call it via corba protocol, when I try with Servlets for testing, I comment those lines